# ls UNIX command : --

Tags: unix, c

I was wondering what the -- in the options of ls stands for

I am coding a ls myself in C and I need to implement it but I can't find what it is about

Any help ? Thanks ❤

Comment: btw, if you're writing one yourself, look into commonly-used libraries like [GNU getopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) that handle the parsing.

Comment: I can't use any external libraries ;)

Comment: Here's my GitHub page for the project : https://GitHub.com/Seluj78/ft_ls

Comment: write
◦ opendir
◦ readdir
◦ closedir
◦ stat
◦ lstat
◦ getpwuid
◦ getgrgid
◦ listxattr
getxattr
◦ time
◦ ctime
◦ readlink
◦ malloc
◦ free
◦ perror
◦ strerror
◦ exit

Comment: And theses are all the functions I'm allowed to use. Of course I've done my personal library, with my own functions like strcmp etc... (the libft repo on my GitHub) same for printf, I've recoded it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply means to stop processing options, so that any following arguments will not be treated as options. This is a convention adopted in many Unix utilities, and is useful if you want to pass an argument that starts with `-`, but don't want it to be treated as an option.

For example, if you want to list details of a file named `-F`, then `ls -l -F` wouldn't do what you want, but `ls -l -- -F` would.

Comment: Thanks for you answer ! So I guess it means that everything after the -- will be treated as files/folders

Comment: But nearly every *nix utility responds to --help. Is --help an option or an argument?

Comment: Technically, anything on the command line is an argument (i.e., the contents of `argv` in a C program). What is considered an "option" is up to the program's interpretation, though it's a very common convention to treat things starting with `-` as options. Accepting `--help` is also just a common convention -- there are many programs that don't. `--help` is an argument to the program (axiomatically). It can be an option to the program if you use, e.g. `ls --help`. It can also not be an option if you use `ls -- --help`.

Comment: @Darren> the common convention has `--` stop option processing. That is, `--` by itself, with no letters attached. /// Other common conventions are single `-` prefix is used for one-letter options and `--` prefix for long options. For instance, compare `ls --all` (long name for -a) and `ls -all` (same as `ls -a -l -l`, duplicate -l being silently ignored). But really, programs are free to do whatever they want. See [`dd`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dd) syntax for instance.